# Does Basis have a standard "const" function?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

Just learning ML and I was looking for a built-in function similar to Haskell's const. It would be defined something like:

```
fun const a b = a
```

Kind of easy to implement myself of course :) but I thought there might be an equivalent standard function that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function in the standard library, so you'll have to define it yourself like you did.